# 'success' dialog after jquery form validation clears and submits - showing success message no matter what

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, jquery-validate

I have a simple email form:

```
<form method="post" action="process-form.php" id="emailForm" name="emailForm" target="_self">
    <h4>Sign up to be notified when we go live!</h4>
<label for="email">E-mail</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"  onclick="return alert('Thanks! Your email has been added.');">

    <p>emails will not be shared with third parties</p>
</form>
```

I am using the following jQuery validation:

```
/*
Created 09/27/09                                        
Questions/Comments: jorenrapini@gmail.com                       
COPYRIGHT NOTICE        
Copyright 2009 Joren Rapini
*/  

$(document).ready(function(){
// Place ID's of all required fields here.
required = ["email"];
// If using an ID other than #email or #error then replace it here
email = $("#email");
errornotice = $("#error");
// The text to show up within a field when it is incorrect
emptyerror = "Please fill out this field.";
emailerror = "Please enter a valid e-mail.";

$("#emailForm").submit(function(){  
    //Validate required fields
    for (i=0;i<required.length;i++) {
        var input = $('#'+required[i]);
        if ((input.val() == "") || (input.val() == emptyerror)) {
            input.addClass("needsfilled");
            input.val(emptyerror);
            errornotice.fadeIn(750);
        } else {
            input.removeClass("needsfilled");
        }
    }
    // Validate the e-mail.
    if (!/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(email.val())) {
        email.addClass("needsfilled");
        email.val(emailerror);
    }

    //if any inputs on the page have the class 'needsfilled' the form will not submit
    if ($(":input").hasClass("needsfilled")) {
        return false;
    } else {
        errornotice.hide();
        return true;
    }
});

// Clears any fields in the form when the user clicks on them
$(":input").focus(function(){       
   if ($(this).hasClass("needsfilled") ) {
        $(this).val("");
        $(this).removeClass("needsfilled");
   }
});
});
```

After the form validates successfully I want a success dialog to display. I kind of have that going now with the `onClick` event for the submit button but obviously that is going to display the message no matter if it validates or not. I think the message needs to be placed in the validation somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your onsubmit function, where you return 'true'.

Comment: would it be something like alert('Thanks!'); ?